# Weight reading out by 404.6kg on Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm programming my Arduino to make a weight scale using the code below.
When there is no weight on the scale it reads -404.6kg. When I add weight the increase is correct, ie when I add 3kg the increase is 3kg and so on, See the screen shot.
I want to add a line to my code the adds the 404.6kg to the load cell reading. how would I do that?

```
#include "HX711.h" 
#define LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN  23
#define LOADCELL_SCK_PIN  22

HX711 scale;

float calibration_factor = -20600; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
//  Serial.println("HX711 calibration sketch");
//  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
//  Serial.println("After readings begin, place known weight on scale");
//  Serial.println("Press + or a to increase calibration factor");
//  Serial.println("Press - or z to decrease calibration factor");

  scale.begin(LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN, LOADCELL_SCK_PIN);
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 0

  long zero_factor = scale.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
  Serial.print("Zero factor: "); //This can be used to remove the need to tare the scale.       
  Serial.println(zero_factor);
}

void loop() {

  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor

  Serial.print("Reading: ");
  Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 1);
  Serial.print(" Kgs"); //Change this to kg and re-adjust the calibration factor if you    follow SI units like a sane person
  Serial.print(" calibration_factor: ");
  Serial.print(calibration_factor);
  Serial.println();

  delay(1000);

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp == '+' || temp == 'a')
      calibration_factor += 10;
    else if(temp == '-' || temp == 'z')
      calibration_factor -= 10;
  }
}
```

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGN97.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're going to need to adjust the `calibration_factor` variable here. I looked into the chip's library, and I saw this comment at the top of a header[1]:

```
Setup your scale and start the sketch WITHOUT a weight on the scale
 Once readings are displayed place the weight on the scale
 Press +/- or a/z to adjust the calibration_factor until the output readings match the known weight
```

and in the code later, where it's defined:

```
float calibration_factor = 2125; //-7050 worked for my 440lb max scale setup
```

So it looks like you should adjust this value until you get a properly calibrated & zeroed read out.

Edit:
I found a tutorial[2] that talks a little more about how to calibrate the sensor, and it also suggests that finding the right number is done by trial-and-adjustment. I don't know what the calibration_factor's units are, or what the number itself represents--but adjusting it should do what you want.

Good luck!

[1] Where I saw the comments:
https://gist.github.com/matt448/14d118e2fc5b6217da11

[2] Look for the section on calibrating the sensor here:
https://circuits4you.com/2016/11/25/hx711-arduino-load-cell/